# How does lightdm auto-login and start a program?

Tags: lightdm, xbmc

I have a user called XBMC

my lightdm.conf looks like this

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=xbmc
autologin-user-timeout=0
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=XBMC
```

it logs in automatically perfectly - but then starts a program /usr/bin/xbmc-standalone - how does it do this?

What I want to do is monitor that process and restart it correctly if it locks (but I need to see how it starts in the first place)

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it looks like it uses

/usr/share/xsessions/XBMC.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XBMC
Comment=This session will start XBMC Media Center
Exec=xbmc-standalone
TryExec=xbmc-standalone
Type=Application
```